# How to get data asynchronously from database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have created a chat app between two users. When client is loaded user1 is assigned a value and user2 is undefined at start. When user clicks on user list button on left side in screenshot then user2 is assigned. So now I have user1 and user2 so now I want to get all the data between user1 and user2 but I get an empty array. How can I call `conversation.find({ $and : [ { user1: user1 }, { user2: user2 } ] })` when user2 is set after click ?

Note: `conversation.find({})` works fine but `conversation.find({ $and : [ { user1: user1 }, { user2: user2 } ] })` is not working.

code below is not working:

```
let conversation = db.collection('conversation'); 
  let user1,user2;

      socket.on('GET_USER', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
         user2 = data.user2;
      });

      socket.on('LOGGEDIN_USER', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
         user1 = data.user1;

         console.log("This is user1 "+ user1)
         console.log("This is user2 "+ user2)

         conversation.find({ $and : [ { user1: user1 }, { user2: user2 } ] }).toArray(function (err, res) {
          if(err){
              throw err;
          }

          console.log(res) 
              // Emit the messages
          io.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', res);
        })

      });
```

screenshot:

[image]

Chat screenshot:

[image]

Comment: try changing your query to conversation.find({ user1: user1, user2: user2 }).toArray(function(err, res) {

Comment: @DanielPérez The current answer works fine. Actually in my chat application. The user1 is received from url params and user2 is only set when some user is set on clicking user from user list so find({}) works fine in this case but `find({ $and : [ { user1: user1 }, { user2: user2 } ] })` doesn't work because user2 is undefined so when user clicks on user from user list (see screenshot) then only user2 gets assigned and then query is success and returns the response. Async behavior of JS is very tricky :(

Comment: @DanielPérez if user clicks on some multiple users from user list i.e user Aditya or user Vineet then on click Aditya should load chat between Mike and Aditya. Similarly when user clicks on Vineet should load chat between Vineet and Mike (Note here Mike is logged in user) . So the current answer is working when user clicks for first time but if user2 is clicked and assigned a new value then it is not working

Comment: @DanielPérez when new value is assigned for user2 everytime click happens on users from userlist it doesn't work. The current answer only works first the first time when user is changed from undefined to either vineet or Aditya (see screenshot for userlist of users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise`s

```
let conversation = db.collection("conversation");
const waitForUser2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    socket.on("GET_USER", function (data) {
        resolve(data.user2);
    });
});
const waitForUser1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    socket.on("LOGGEDIN_USER", function (data) {
        resolve(data.user1);
    });
});
Promise.all([
    waitForUser1,
    waitForUser2
]).then(([user1, user2]) => {
    console.log("This is user1 " + user1);
    console.log("This is user2 " + user2);
    conversation.find({
        $and: [
            {user1: user1},
            {user2: user2}
        ]
    }).toArray(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(res);
        // Emit the messages
        io.emit("RECEIVE_MESSAGE", res);
    });
});
```

Comment: The current answer works fine. Actually in my chat application. The user1 is received from url params and user2 is only set when some user is set on clicking user from user list so find({}) works fine in this case but `find({ $and : [ { user1: user1 }, { user2: user2 } ] })` doesn't work because user2 is undefined so when user clicks on user from user list (see screenshot) then only user2 gets assigned and then query is success and returns the response.

Comment: Your answer is correct but if user clicks on some multiple users from user list i.e user Aditya or user Vineet then on click Aditya should load chat between Mike and Aditya. Similarly when user clicks on Vineet should load chat between Vineet and Mike (Note here Mike is logged in user) . So your answer is working when user clicks for first time but if user2 is clicked and assigned a new value then it is not working

Comment: when new value is assigned for user2 everytime click happens on users from userlist it doesn't work. The current answer only works first the first time when user is changed from undefined to either vineet or Aditya (see screenshot for userlist of users).

Comment: If you have another problem please ask another question